# Cannot insert data in MYSQL Using Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Need help with the below. I am unable to understand what is incorrect in the below code. 
I have also check the MYSQL names and HTML Form. No errors there.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
String Week=request.getParameter("Week");
String Metric=request.getParameter("Metric");
String Method=request.getParameter("Method");
String Region=request.getParameter("Region");
String TI=request.getParameter("TI");
String ASSA=request.getParameter("ASSA");
String TM=request.getParameter("TM");
String Skilled=request.getParameter("Skilled");
String center=request.getParameter("center");
String caller_id=request.getParameter("caller_id");
String observer=request.getParameter("observer");
String Observations=request.getParameter("Observations");

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/compliance_form","root","mypass");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate("insert into form1 (Week,Metric,Method,Region,TI,ASSA,TM,Skilled,center,caller_id,observer,Observations) values('"+Week+"','"+Metric+"','"+Method+"','"+Region+"','"+TI+"','"+ASSA+"','"+TM+"','"+Skilled+"','"+center+"','"+caller_id+"','"+observer+"','"+Observations+"')");
    response.sendRedirect("save.html");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    response.sendRedirect("error.html");
}

%>
```

Comment: First things first: You are leaving yourself open to Sql Injection attacks; you should be using prepared statements. Question: With this particular driver, is AutoCommit initially true or false? If if is false, you will have to either call `commit` on the connection after the call to `executeUpdate` or call `setAutoCommit(true)` on the connection before calling `executeUpdate`. But ultimately what is the problem? An error message? No update? Something else?

Comment: There is no error message. The Mysql Table doesn't get updated and the code is executing the below code only-

catch(Exception e)
{
    response.sendRedirect("error.html");
}

Comment: Then you definitely need to output the exception (perhaps in a log file?) before redirecting. Also, look at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html for an example on how to use a prepared statement. It not only defends against SQL Injection attacks but also handles situations where an input field has a quote (`'`) character, which would be a problem for you with your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data was not inserted there was probably an exception.
I'd start by trying to capture possible error messages.

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    response.sendRedirect("error.html");
}
```

This should give you additional error information in your IDE console or application server log you can proceed on.

Code in JSP is generally pretty hard to debug. If you have the option you might want to migrate the logic into a Java class.

Comment: Thanks Roland. There was one additional 's' in the field name. I was able to find that after using 
e.printStackTrace();